# SugarCRM CE (6.5.x) How To Create a View Layout with Panels (not fields) in Two (Multiple) Columns (Side by Side Subpanels)

Tags: sugarcrm

Sugar 6.5 CE

In Studio View Layout Editor (this happens to be for Cases Edit View but should apply to all view layouts) I see no way for me to move a panel into a second column to the side of another panel. This is frustrating in that many people (like myself) are using 1920 pixel width video displays these days so you get this stack of panels with extremely wide tables, way wider than necessary to display the list data of the panel.

How can I go about moving the panels into two columns like you can do when you edit the layout of the Dashboard where you can move dashlets side by side. If I have to do some coding, so be it.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can throw a bone out on this one.

(I'm NOT talking about adding columns for fields within a panel.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that can be achived through code. Studio doesn't support that.

copy modules/Cases/metadata/editviewdefs.php to custom/modules/Cases/metadata/editviewdefs.php
or edit existing custom/modules/Cases/metadata/editviewdefs.php

```
$viewdefs['Cases']['EditView'] = array(
    'templateMeta' => array(
         'form' => array(
             'buttons'=>array('SAVE', 'CANCEL')
          ),
          'maxColumns' => '2', 
          'useTabs' => true,
          'widths' => array(
               array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30'),
               array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30'),
          ),                         
'panels' => array(
.
.
.
... file goes on
```

Here increase maxColumns and add elements in widths accordingly.

Than you have to arrange the fields in panels to match you column layout.

other optical changes can be made through 'customcode' , 'displayParams' or by javascript